# How do I use an app that somebody else created but didn't build?

Tags: android, ide, apk

I downloaded an app from GitHub but it does not include an APK file. I am using an Android device and I do not have access to Android Studio. How would I used aide or something else to build the app? (GitHub page: https://github.com/mumumusuc/joycon-toolkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `apk` files in the Release bundles: https://github.com/mumumusuc/joycon-toolkit/releases (click on assets to expand).

Comment: Would I have to add the APK to the Android folder?

Comment: You need to get it to your device somehow. You can even upload it to google drive or something, then download on your phone, and just open - this should start installation if no other restrictions are set.

Comment: The app just closes as soon as it opens so I assumed it needed the files that are included in the zip file.

Comment: No, you probably don't have permissions on your phone to install the apks directly (other than from the PlayStore), check Install from Unknown Sources method
 paragraph here: https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-install-apks-31494/.. if you can't find it, search for the same problem but for your phone and Android version

Comment: I have these settings enabled and the app is installed. When I load the app it just flashes white and closes.

Comment: Then something's probably wrong with the APK. Can't help you in that regard. You can create an issue in the Github repo and ask this question so maybe the maintainer will answer you: https://github.com/mumumusuc/joycon-toolkit/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible. Because there is no other way to compile the code of Android Studio to make it runnable. And the link which you have shared is not an Android Studio Code it is Flutter Code. Which requires a different environment than Android Studio.

If you really need that software create an issue on Github and ask developer for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository, open it in VScode, in terminal type flutter build apk ( if you have PC or laptop ) otherwise on phone i dont think its doable.